# Using ranking functions without order by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got a PostgreSQL database. There is a query that orders rows by `some_date` and `minutes`. The result looks like this:

```
id|is_smth|some_date |minutes
35|true   |2021-11-10|985
36|true   |2021-11-19|684
35|true   |2021-11-25|605
34|false  |null      |null
```

Then, I have tried applying `DENSE_RANK()` to it, to implement pagination in my application, but it does not work as I need it to, as it has to order the rows by given columns.

What I am trying to achieve is just giving the rank to each row by the criteria specified in the original `ORDER BY` clause plus the `id` of the result set without changing their order. So, it would look like this:

```
id|is_smth|some_date |minutes|rank
35|true   |2021-11-10|985    |1   
36|true   |2021-11-19|684    |2   
35|true   |2021-11-25|605    |1   
34|false  |null      |null   |3
```

I have to retrieve the first two rows AND all of the associated data with them (in this case it would be all of the other rows with ids 35 and 36). Is it possible?

Comment: Rows in a table do not have any implied sort order. If you want a guaranteed sort order, you **have** to use `order by`. If you need the rank by `id` then you have to use `order by id`

Comment: The rows in the query are sorted by `some_date` and `minutes` columns initially. I have to retrieve the first two rows AND all of the associated data with them (in this case it would be all of the other rows with `id`s 35 and 36.

Comment: The `order by` of a window function (`dense_rank()`)  is independent of the `order by` of the overall query.

Comment: I know that, and that is, basically, the core of a problem

Comment: Why is that a problem. Just use `dense_rank() over (order by some_date, minutes, id)`

Comment: I can't, because it ruins the pagination. If I do like you say, then rows with the same `id` would have different ranks and there is a possibility of not retrieving ALL the data related to that `id` Lets say, I have 5 rows with `id` 35 in the result set and my pagination filter limit is set to 3. As a result, I would get only 3 rows, instead of 5.

Comment: But, if the final rank is equal for them, then it would work.

Comment: Why don't you use ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK for pagination ?